# How to pass active user's email from a wordpress site to an external shiny R app?

Tags: r, wordpress, shiny

I have an app running on an R shiny server and i display it on my wordpress site using iframe.
I need a way to pass the e-mail of the active user from wordpress into the shiny app.

Comment: The current user can be retrieved in PHP via the [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/). The potentially unsafe but simple method would be to just use that and pass the email as a query string over to your iframe.